# Is it possible to get old suggestion system back in Firefox 43.0?

Tags: firefox, search

With the new update, the first suggested link is just domain. In older versions, the first suggested link was the page I visited the most and I got used to this great feature.

Is it possible to remove the new domain suggestion, for example "Visit ebay.co.uk"?

See image attached[image]

Comment: It seems to be some kind of "sponsored link". In my url Facebook usually ranks 2nd or 3rd, yet this feature constantly suggests FB as #1 after typing "fa".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update: This preference no longer exists in Firefox 48.0.** See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1111480/is-it-possible-to-get-old-suggestion-system-back-in-firefox-48-0) for Firefox 48.0.

I noticed this today too and played around in `about:config`. To get rid of the "Visit website" suggestion you'll need to change a preference. The value you want to change is `browser.urlbar.unifiedcomplete`, set it to **false**.

**Set it to false:**
[image: urlbar]

**Back to normal:**

[image: Search Suggestions]

Comment: Perfect. This has been annoying me too!

Comment: @DavidPostill Setting browser.urlbar.delay to 0 speeds up the search response, too.