# How can I help Safari's autocomplete find the right site

Tags: safari, autocomplete

The site I visit most often is `umich.instructure.com`.  Unfortunately, that page then loads several resources from urls in the form `umich.instructure.com/_____`.  For whatever reason, Safari now assumes I want to navigate to `umich.instructure.com/dashboard-sidebar` whenever I type `u` into the address bar.

Is there anyway to edit autocomplete preferences?  Or is there a way to "trick" Safari into preferring the correct site (perhaps by reloading it a few hundred times with a script)?

[How can I stop Firefox from autocompleting the wrong site in the location bar?](https://superuser.com/questions/1039391/how-can-i-stop-firefox-from-autocompleting-the-wrong-site-in-the-location-bar) is similar, but for a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try bookmarking the right URL. I believe bookmarks are preferred over history URLs.

Comment: This is a good idea, but somehow it doesn't work... do you think it's worth trying to send in a bug/feedback to apple?