# Is it possible to get old suggestion system back in Firefox 48.0?

Tags: firefox, search

With new update 48.0, Firefox shows the domain as first result once again, but
this time changing `browser.urlbar.unifiedcomplete` does not help. So let me ask
once again:

Is it possible to remove the new domain suggestion, for example “Visit
ebay.co.uk”? Example screenshot:

> [image: visit screenshot]

---

Follow up:

I found [this reddit thread](//reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/4vv2qt) which links to
[a Bugzilla report](//bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1291175), and there is no option to disable it.

> We spent time working on improving the awesomebar, and we think we did. You
>   don't like what we did, that's fine, we accept your opinion, but we are not
>   going to throw away all the work just because of that.

Related:

[Is it possible to get old suggestion system back in Firefox 43.0?](//superuser.com/q/1014611)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the `browser.urlbar.unifiedcomplete` preference is gone, I tried playing around with the other preferences but couldn't get rid of the annoying "Visit ..." suggestion.

Here are the workarounds I've found:

## userChrome.css

This is what I am using and it works fine for me.

> If you want to list 10 entries, change 'browser.urlbar.maxRichResults' in about:config to 11 and then use the following lines in userChrome.css:

```
#PopupAutoCompleteRichResult richlistitem:first-of-type[actiontype="searchengine"],
#PopupAutoCompleteRichResult richlistitem[actiontype="visiturl"] { visibility:collapse !important; }
#PopupAutoCompleteRichResult .autocomplete-richlistbox {
height: auto !important;
max-height: calc(31px * 10) !important;
}
```

> If you don't already have a userChrome.css file, you'll also need to add the following lines at the top of the file:

```
/* Do not remove the @namespace line -- it's required for correct functioning */
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* set default namespace to XUL */
```

Source: http://www.ghacks.net/2016/08/01/firefox-48-release/#comment-3950665

Result:

[image: Suggestions]

## Stylish

You can also achieve this using Stylish.

> 1. Install [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)
> 2. Install the [URL Bar Tweaks - Remove Visit/Search & Scroll bar style](https://userstyles.org/styles/122394/url-bar-tweaks-remove-visit-search-scroll-bar)

Source: http://www.ghacks.net/2015/12/21/how-to-remove-visit-in-firefoxs-address-bar/

Comment: Your linked style also offers the old 2 line layout, nice!

Comment: Stylish style works perfect for me, no hassle, so I am accepting your answer, thanks. Also as @StevenPenny noticed it also offerst 2 line layout which is much better.

Comment: worked for me but single line layout, not 2 line layout like @StevenPenny. Why? Anyway, Thanks. +1

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to try the following setting in `about:config`:

```
keyword.enable
```

Set it to `false` and only urls will be valid.

If you want to search using a provider sometimes, you can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> combination to switch to that mode when needed.